# Despoina Leviathan DLC How to get past the enemies?

Tags: mass-effect-3, me3-leviathan

In Leviathan DLC, on Despoina how do you get past the Brute attack and still pick up power cells from Cortez? I tried running all over the place to get to Cortez, but died as many times.

I am in my final push to get to Leviathan, just unable to get to Cortez.

I tried killing all the enemies from cover, but the waves *never end.*

Normally in these situations, there is a gun available that can help with the fight. But I have not found such gun, and the enemies are kicking me where it hurts.

So how to achieve my goal to get to the Leviathan?

Comment: What class are you? It should be easy as an infiltrator or vanguard. Other classes may need to be more methodical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to not focus on the enemies. The goal is to power the ship, not kill the enemies. As you've seen, the enemies never stop coming.

I got past this part by sprinting to the next power port whenever I got a new power cell from Cortez. If any enemies were in my way, I'd shoot them but other than that I would ignore any enemies since they take a long time to take down (especially the Brutes).

For me, it took 3 power cells to fully power the doors. I believe that the various ports can be reused, if needed.

Comment: Actually, you just have to get the power to 100%. Once you've done that, the mech is powered up and you can proceed.

Comment: Glad you were able to get past the hard part. :)